# How to get user wise list from user rate table in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I want to get user list group wise in mysql query

My table is like below

```
id    user_id    price
1     3          25
2     2          45
3     5          10
4     2          5
6     3          2
```

So how can i make query in mysql to get following result as

```
user_id   price
2         50
3         27
5         10
```

In the above example, i am going to sum of price for same user_id and listing will be showing as top price on the top.

Is there any idea, how can i do it in mysql query?

Comment: Thats a very basic sum and group by query.

Comment: I am new in mysql, can you help me by providing this query?

Comment: You're supposed to do the studying and research first, then ask in SO if you can't get it to work. SO is not a replacement for learning how to program by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

you can  simply groupby user_id and sum the price using builtin function.

```
      SELECT totprice, user_id         
      FROM
(
    SELECT SUM(price) as totprice, user_id         FROM tablename 
    GROUP BY user_id         
) as table1
       ORDER BY 
totprice
```

Comment: @NileshDharmik have you tried above query . you need take output of one queery as table or second to do orderby

Comment: @NileshDharmik if any of these answers ,worked for you kindly accept that answer by clicking click icon there, it will help other users looking for answer. And will earn some reputation for you and answerer.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT user_id,sum(`price`) as price FROM table GROUP BY user_id
```

Comment: try using `ORDER by price desc`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Select distinct user_id, sum(price) from yourtable group by user_id;
```